# Floated divs not clearing as expected in IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have encountered a rather pesky bug which only seems to happen with Internet Explorer. I have created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/381m3vq4/5/) to illustrate my frustration.

```
<div class="container" style="width: 802px;">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

The 4th block does not clear to the left even though the top three blocks are of the same computed height. Does anyone know of any solution/hack for this?

I need this to work with min-height, not height and I cannot use clear: left.

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due simply to the fact that the first two blocks are 1 pixel taller than the other two.

This causes the 4th block to catch the right edge of the 2nd block.

If you set the height of `.block` to 160px, for example, you will see that they wrap as you intended.

This is a common problem if floated elements have non-similar heights.

**Note:** The reason the behavior may appear to be browser dependent may have to do with the default font and font size that may vary across browsers.  If you were to use a slightly smaller font, then the first two blocks would be slightly shorter and all the blocks would then take on the min height of 155px, and be the same, so the problem would not manifest itself. (Set `font-size: 0.75em` on `.block` and see what happens!)

```js
$('.block').each(function (i) {
    $('body').append('height of block' + i + ': ' + $(this).outerHeight() + '\n');
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 802px;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  overflow: auto;
}
.block {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 40px;
  border: 10px solid #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  min-height: 155px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing eli.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscin.</div>
  <div class="block">Lorel eum</div>
  <div class="block">Lorem ipsumdentur parum clari,um.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are right in saying that the text inside the blocks have some influence. Perhaps the line-height has something to do with it but the computed heights are all equal which is confusing.

For now i have just added an extra 1px to each height value and it seems to have worked for now.

Comment: Keep in mind that the computed height will vary depending on the font size and the line height.  As long as length of your content is reasonable, you won't have any problems.